# SharePoint 2007 - How to update all links globally

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, powershell, migration

We are going to be changing the FQDN of our SharePoint site during a migration

```
http://oursharepoint.ext1.com
```

will be

```
http://outsharepoint.ext2.com
```

And I need a way to tell SharePoint, go find any thing that has `ext1` and replace it with `ext2`.

The issue is that our setup is running PowerShell 2.0 which cannot do this:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

and I absolutely need that snap-in to be able to run something like [this MSDN tutorial on how to Update Links On Site Relocation.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/09/26/how-to-fix-navigational-links-after-relocating-a-site-collection/)

I even tried the depracated function `loadWithPartialName` and it still didn't load anything.

Comment: quick confirmation - you are using the SharePoint Powershell console with RunAsAdmin or just tried to use a standard PowerShell prompt?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I was running standard PowerShell prompt

Comment: ok, I will try to doublecheck if I can find anything about Powershell versions incompatibilities like you seem to suggest, but in the meantime please ensure you try running the prompt in administrator mode (simply use the RunAsAdministrator context menu option when you right click the shortcut)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist So I am right in using the standard powershell console instead of the SharePoint Powershell console?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Since I'm running SharePoint 2007, there is no SharePoint Management Console.

Comment: .... guess that that detail was missing ^_^. Then, I fear I'll have to agree with what Denis pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell** power shell snapin for MOSS 2007. The first version of PowerShell commands was released for SharePoint 2010

Also, your snippet suggests that you are running PowerShell v4:

> No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell **version 4**

Can you try to do a Proof-of-concept migration first and see what links are incorrect? I predict that navigation should be fine since it should use relative links. The biggest problem you will probably face, is that you will have to modify the hyperlinks that users added on the pages. You might need to create a small console application to go recursively across all pages modifying the links using regex.

Comment: The reason it looked like it was version 4 was because that was on my local machine, not the sharepoint server. The Sharepoint server is running powershell v2.

Comment: After more research, it looks like you can load modules into PowerShell v2 using `loadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SharePoint')` however, I'm not familiar enough with c# to use those functions. Makes me wonder if at this point it would be better to write a c# script instead of using powershell

Comment: using C# makes total sense here